# Separation between name and surname using datalists

Tags: php, mysql, datalist

I'm using a [datalist](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp) to store all of the names and surnames in that I retrieve from a MySQL database table.

When someone inputs the name **and** surname of a tutor and clicks "show tutor", showTutor() is called.

```
<input list="tutorData" name="tutors" id="tutorToShow">
<datalist id="tutorData">
    <?php
    $sql = "SELECT name, surname FROM tutors ORDER BY surname ASC";
    if (!$res = $link->query($sql)) {
        trigger_error('error in query ' . $link->error);
    } else {
        while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
            $name = $row['surname'];
            $sName = $row['name'];
            ?>

            <option value="<?php echo "$sName $name" ?>" >
                <?php
            }
        }
        ?>
</datalist>
<input type="button" value="Weergeven" onclick="showTutor();">
```

My datalist is filled up and works perfectly. Now: When showTutor is called, so when the button was clicked:

```
function showTutor(){
   var tut = document.getElementById("tutorToShow").value;
}
```

This gives me something like John Smith or Mary Jane Dough.

**What the problem is though**, when I reload the shown tutor div with ajax, I need to retrieve that tutor's ID from the database.

So what I'll definitely need is this SQL:

```
SELECT ID
FROM tutors
WHERE name LIKE '$name%'
AND surname LIKE '$surname%'
```

Now I just need to separate the name.

In other words, how do I retrieve the ID from a table with columns ID, name, surname, without knowing the separation between name or surname?

John Smith: easy, first word is name, second word is surname

Mary Jane Dough: now what?

I thought of adding a comma that seperates both names, but that's not very stylish.

Another option is to add a column to my database that has both names in one record, but that's a hassle when new tutors need to be added.

Comment: Add the ID of the record as a 'data-id="xx"' property to the <option> and then send that using javascript to directly fetch the row.

Comment: Then what happens when a user types rather than select it from the dropdown? What if a full name is copied from somewhere?

Comment: If I understand correctly, a typed or copied name can only match records defined in your datalist. So you should be able to find the id that was added to the matching datalist record. I've tested the datalist element on https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist

Comment: Okay, but then I'll need to check whether my datalist contains the option that was typed or copied by the user? If not, it can only be submitted after clicking the option that pops up, otherwise there is no ID.

Comment: Yeah looks like it..is it a problem that a user should click the option?

Comment: The least clicks the better, I suppose. I'd want to be able to click submit if the entered value was the same as the one that popped up..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73332/discussion-between-oli-and-michiel).

Comment: Question solved in chat - posting answer later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry for the delay, @Oli helped me in chat a few weeks ago.

```
<input list="tutorData" name="tutors" id="tutorToShow">
<datalist id="tutorData">
    <?php
    $sql = "SELECT name, surname, id FROM tutors ORDER BY surname ASC";
    if (!$res = $link->query($sql)) {
        trigger_error('error in query ' . $link->error);
    } else {
        while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
            $name = $row['surname'];
            $sName = $row['name'];
            $id = $row['id'];
            ?>

            <option value="<?php echo "$sName $name" ?>" data-id="<?php echo $id; ?>">
                <?php
            }
        }
        ?>
</datalist>
<input type="button" value="Show" onclick="showTutor();">
```

So basically I've only added a data-id, I then wrote this javascript:

```
<script>
    function showTutor() {
        var tut = document.getElementById("tutorToShow").value;
        var list = document.getElementById("tutorData");
        var length = list.options.length;
        var id;
        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            var eachTutor = list.options[i].value.toLowerCase();
            if (tut === eachTutor) {
                id = list.options[i].getAttribute('data-id');
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

I now have the id of the tutor, without separating any name. I also post it to a php page with ajax, but that is not relevant to the question.

Thanks again to the ones that helped.

Answer (score 0):

Do this before you assign the data into your elements

```
if (strpos($sName, ' ') != false) {
    // if above string position of space isn't false,
    // explode the string at the space into an array of
    // individual names.
    $sName = explode(' ', $sName);
    echo $sNames[0];
    echo $sNames[1];
    // you will need to look at foreach loop and counting the array length
}
```

Try this.

```
<datalist id="tutorData">
<?php
$sql = "SELECT name, surname FROM tutors ORDER BY surname ASC";
if (!$res = $link->query($sql)) {
    trigger_error('error in query ' . $link->error);
} else {
    while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
        $surname = $row['surname'];
        $first_names = $row['name'];
        if (strpos($first_names, ' ') != false) {
            /*
               if above string position of space isn't false,
               explode the string at the space into an array of
               individual names.
            */
            $first_name = explode(' ', $first_names); // EG: Paul John
            $name1 = $first_name[0]; // Paul
            $name2 = $first_name[1]; // John
            /* 
               you will need to look at foreach loop and counting
               the array length  
            */
    }

    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $name1 . ' ' . $name2 . ' ' . $surname" ?>" >
    <?php
    }
}
?>
</datalist>
```

Comment: I'm not sure about how I'm supposed to put this into practice, you separate the surname into an array, then what? I'll need to do the same for the other name?

Comment: this checks your variable $sName for a space which is name from the database. i assume thats first names EG: robert paul or alison diane and a separate field for surnames. The explode splits the string into and array at the spaces (the spaces are not added to the array).

Comment: So what if my surnames consist of several spaces as well?

Comment: Just use the same code but change the variables being split.

Comment: I've never used this before, sorry if I'm asking dumb questions: $sNames is now an array by itself? `$sNames[0] = alison`,` $sNames[1] = diane?`, so I'd need to add those arrays of names to one large array and then what? I don't see how it helps me..

Comment: Looking at your code above.

$row is the array,
$name is the $row['surname'] value which should be a single word string.

So when you do the explode is shouldnt explode on spaces as there are none.

By doing it on $sName variable (yes i think you have them reversed) as it stands now that one may or may not have more than one name hence the If part of the code, IF it has space(s) execute within, if not just use the variable (this was why i named them the same, so one will overwrite the other if its executed.